# How to output following month?

Tags: apex, date

I need to add the text for the following month in a newsletter. So for example in September to add the text for October.

Comment: Please provide any examples of what you have tried so far - including code snippets, etc.

Answer (score 3):

In situations like these, it's generally a good idea to try to find documentation to see if Salesforce provides the tools you need to solve the problem you're working on.

In this case, the [documentation on the DateTime class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm) will be helpful. If you haven't bookmarked the various [developer documentation guides](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/), googling for "apex [class name here]" (e.g. "apex datetime") generally works.

For this, the `DateTime.format(String dateFormatString)` method is the one you'll want to use.

The approach we'll take is:

- get the current day/time
- add one month
- format the `DateTime` to give you the name of the month

in code:

```java
// DateTime.now() is another built-in method of the DateTime class that returns
//   an instance of DateTime that represents the current date and time
DateTime ourDT = DateTime.now();

// The add<time period>() methods return a new instance of DateTime as a result
//   instead of modifying the existing instance itself.
// That's why we re-assign the result of the method call back to ourDT.
// This could be combined with the first line of code, but I keep it separate here
//   for demonstration.
ourDt = ourDT.addMonths(1);

// Date format strings follow Java's Simple Date Format ( http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html )
// 'M' is the symbol used to grab the Month (as a number)
// 'MM' does the same thing, but zero-pads the month (i.e. '09' for September, no difference for October - December)
// 'MMM' grabs the month as the abbreviated string (e.g. 'Oct' for 'October')
// 'MMMM' grabs the month as a full string
String nextMonth = ourDT.format('MMMM');
```